# Possible to determine the next value based on previous data?

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I'm mainly a programmer with very, very basic maths knowledge (only +/-/x/÷) and I have a dataset I need to predict some data from it. The data is basic, but I don't know how to find a formula that I can apply in code to do it. Let me explain:

I have a system that generates a "random" value (and by "random" I mean that I want to prove it's not exactly random) that can be either A, B or C. My question is, based on a sample of say, 1000 or 5000 rows, where each row has a result (A, B or C) is it possible to predict the next result based on either statistics or "machine learning" to find patterns/flaw in the data generation **based** on the previous data? This is important, I want to use the previous data to figure out the next value, or at least some statistics?

Any kind of help/pointers is really welcome. Bonus points if it's in python or pseudocode or simple/linear representation as I'll be able to translate that to code, or something that doesn't look like math formulas because my brain explodes, sorry!

Comment: in 1000 rows, it's gauranteed one result shows up at least 334 times. in 5000 rows, it's guaranteed one result will show up at least 1667 times.

Comment: Why, thank you good sir. Exactly what I need to know - the question is, how did you come out with that conclusion? For instance, for row 1001, or 5001, how can I predict that the next value "should" be A? (even if it errors, that's okay to have a margin of errors, but with a high row count, error probability could/should be low, I guess?)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee nevermind, figured it out with a division. Makes sense, but my dataset, for, let's say C, has a very low probability (let's say around 1.5 times out of 100), so what do I do about A & B? (my goal is to be able to predict which one of the 3 values will come up next)

Comment: pigeonhole principle, an intuitional combinatorial argument

Comment: You need the concepts of Statistical Process Control (or maybe other names - people keep inventing new names for the same quality control concepts). These are used in manufacturing to monitor processes, looking for trends in the variations in measurements of the items produced. The idea is to spot trends and correct for them before the items being manufactured go outside of allowable tolerances. There are a number of statistical tools developed for this, including some that apply to cases such as yours where there are only a limited number of possible outcomes. Look for "six sigma".